# Import data from ARC Scene (ARCGIS) to Blender

Tags: import

I am trying to import a 3D model of a landscape I created in arc scene (ARC GIS) to blender, but I am not able to find a way to do it.

I tried to follow the method suggested in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXgLdyCLumI using VRML format, but it did not work for me. (Maybe I am doing something wrong)

It will be of great help if anyone can suggest how to do it.

Comment: This is a severely outdated video. Can you export it in another 3d format like obj, fbx, dae or dxf ?

Comment: ARCscene allows export only in .wrl format and not in anyother format